# Why doesn't C++ return a double on division?

Tags: c++

I am trying to divide two integers and want the exact answer in double.
My code works fine for small values:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int max = 100;
    int min = 10;
    int n = 8;
    double gap = (max-min)/(double)(n-1);
    cout<<gap<<endl;
}
```

This prints 12.8571

But when I run this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int max = 99404748;
    int min = 925679;
    int n = 240;
    double gap = (max-min)/(double)(n-1);
    cout<<gap<<endl;
}
```

It prints 412046 while the actual answer is 412046.3138

What is the reason for this behaviour? Also, how can I fix it?

Comment: Play with the std::ios_base::flags (fixed, scientific) and precision

Comment: Maybe the "You don't pay for what you don't use principle". If you want double, you can ask for it.

Comment: @Galik, The title is rather misleading. There's no integer division involved.

Comment: The division does return a double. In fact, you're declaring the variable gap to be a double, and it is.  The problem is in how you're using the cout stream.

Answer (score 7):

Everything with your `double` value is fine. The result you see is just a matter of how it's represented in the `std::ostream`.

Use the [`fixed` and `setprecision()` I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), to change the behavior of the representation:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int max = 99404748;
    int min = 925679;
    int n = 240;
    double gap = (max-min)/(double)(n-1);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(4) <<gap<<endl;
         // ^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ae9e93482146db9)

Comment: Why does it print a decimal number with other set of values, such as the first example?@PeterSmith

Comment: @ShreyanshDoshi It's defaulting to 6 digits of precision.